# How to set the fill extrusion height in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

in Mapbox Studio, I'm trying to set the height of an extrusion layer to a value that is mapped to the identity values of the layer property but I cannot find the option.

My layer data have the property `upper_val_m` that contains the height
in meters of each polygon.

In Mapbox Studio I have the option to map the height value to the data value "exponential", "interval" or "categorical" but none of those seems to allow an "identity" mapping directly to the data value.

What did I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

ok, I found a way to add this by directly editing the json of the style and using

```
{
  "base": 1,
  "type": "identity",
  "property": "upper_val_m"
}
```

[image]